# Function of a closure equal to closure of the function of original set?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous and $S$ is some set. Can we say that $ f(\overline{S}) = \overline{f(S)}$?

To me it seems intuitive that if we map a closed set to some output space then the output is the closure of something. But is that something necessarily $f(S)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, continity is only equvalent to $f\left[\overline S\right]\subseteq\overline{f[S]}$ for all $S$. A function such that $f\left[\overline S\right]\supseteq \overline {f[S]}$ for all $S$ is called a *closed* function. In general, continuous does not imply closed, see for instance the map $x\mapsto \begin{cases}x^2&\text{if }x<0\\ \arctan x&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$, from  $\Bbb R$ to $[0,\infty)$. It maps the closed set $[0,\infty)$ to $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: @Methmath For functions $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ and bounded subsets, yes, by Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 0):

> To me it seems intuitive that if we map a closed set to some output space then the output is the closure of something.

That is not true. A continuous function may map a closed set to a non-closed one.
Consider for example the inclusion
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
(0,1) & \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow}  & \mathbb{R}\\
x & \mapsto & x
\end{array}.$$
The set $S = (0,1)$ is closed in $(0,1)$, but $i(S)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.